# How can I update a column based on a value of another table in one query?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have:

- a table `person` with a column `personshallow_ptr_id`
- a table `personshallow` with a column `entity_ptr_id`

I want to remove `personshallow` and have `entity_ptr_id` in `person`

So I've made a column `entity_ptr_id` in `person`, and I would like to do this query:

"for each `personshallow_ptr_id` of `person`, take its corresponding `entity_ptr_id` in `personshallow` and assign it to `entity_ptr_id` of `person`

Here's the create table if you have not enough information:

```
create table person
(
    personshallow_ptr_id integer not null
        constraint person_personshallow_ptr_id_d7009fc0_pk
            primary key
        constraint person_personshallow_ptr_id_d7009fc0_uniq
            unique
        constraint person_personshallow_ptr_id_d7009fc0_fk_perso
            references personshallow
            deferrable initially deferred
)

create table personshallow
(
    entity_ptr_id integer not null
        constraint personshallow_pkey
            primary key
        constraint personshallow_entity_ptr_id_b43d70c2_fk_entity_id
            references entity
            deferrable initially deferred
);
```

The main objective is to remove the table `personshallow`

Comment: 1. your tables both have only one column? So, every personshallow_ptr_id exists as entity_ptr_id? So, shallow is a subset of person: So why do you need any operation? Maybe you should add some sample code 2. If there is really only one column the unique constraint is not necessary because this is ensured by the PK

Comment: I recommend against doing this, because the `personshallow` already maintains this relationship, and there is no obvious need to duplicate it.

Comment: I want to remove `personshallow` because it's useless. We've already removed all the code that access this table. There's only this `personshallow` table, which will never be used, left in PostGreSQL. I want to remove it forever and make a "direct" link from `person` to `person_entity_id`

Comment: @S-Man `person` is a subset of `personshallow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somthing like this ? (your code is not working for table creation so I assume there is something to identify which person is in personshallow)

```
UPDATE person c
SET entity_ptr_id = c2.entity_ptr_id 
FROM personshallow c2
WHERE c.personshallow_ptr_id  = c2.personshallow_ptr_id
```

EDIT
So, after discussion :

```
ALTER TABLE public.app_person
DROP CONSTRAINT app_person_personshallow_ptr_id_d7009fc0_fk_app_perso;
```

After that drop your person_shallow table, rename your column if needed, and create a new foreign key on your person table ;)

Comment: I dont know PostGreSQL, so are you sure that the column `personshallow_ptr_id` is present in the table `personshallow`? (Maybe yes, because `person` is a subset of `personshallow`)

Comment: 'personshallow_ptr_id' is not a PG system table. It is one of your tables. So you should know ;) Not me :) Use an editor like dbeaver or pgadmin to have the precise script of your tables.

Comment: I did a `CTRL-q` under `PyCharm` to show the "`create table`" = that's what I copied/paste in my question, there's nothing more.

Comment: When I try to copy-paste your code like this `UPDATE public.app_person c
SET entity_ptr_id = c2.entity_ptr_id 
FROM public.app_personshallow c2
WHERE c.personshallow_ptr_id  = c2.` (and I ask for auto-completion), I only get `entity_ptr_id` as column, hence my question specific to `PostGreSQL` here

Comment: What you asked is how join two tables to update one of them. I answered to that. But here is the thing : those tables are not postgresql native ones. So, if you want to join a table and another one you have to know which column identify the other table. If you do not have any, then it is impossible.

Comment: BUT : the code output extract from your tool is not good. 'constraint person_personshallow_ptr_id_d7009fc0_fk_perso
            references personshallow' do not refere any column. So, please, use DBeaver or PGadmin to have the good declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199191/discussion-between-jaisus-and-olivier-pons).